# ASP.Net MVC Strongly Typed View With Multiple Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller which peforms a linq to sql query against a model consiting of 4 tables.

```
 var files = from f in filesContext.Files
                    join u in filesContext.aspnet_Users on f.Uploader equals u.UserId
                    join uir in filesContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals uir.UserId
                    join ur in filesContext.aspnet_Roles on uir.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                    select f;
```

I then return the view passing files variable as the model.

In the view I currently have:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Bailiffs.Models.File>>"
```

This is fine until I want to access columns from any other table except Files e.g. aspnet_Users or aspnet_Rols. I guess this is because my view knows nothing of those models. How can i gain access to those models in my view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only returning "f" from the query, which is why you don't see the rest.

```
 var files = from f in filesContext.Files
                    join u in filesContext.aspnet_Users on f.Uploader equals u.UserId
                    join uir in filesContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals uir.UserId
                    join ur in filesContext.aspnet_Roles on uir.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                    select new { f, u, uir, ur};
```

You will need of course define a named type (class) to hold "f", "u", "uir", "ur".

```
class FileInfo
{
    public FileType File { get; set; }
    public UserType User { get; set; }
    public UserInRoleType UserInRole { get; set; }
    public UserRoleType UserRole { get; set; }
}


 var files = from f in filesContext.Files
                    join u in filesContext.aspnet_Users on f.Uploader equals u.UserId
                    join uir in filesContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals uir.UserId
                    join ur in filesContext.aspnet_Roles on uir.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                    select new FileInfo { File = f, User = u, UserInRole = uir, UserRole = ur};
```

Then in your view:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Bailiffs.Models.FileInfo>>"
```

Comment: Probably no need for a UserInRole property since it undoubtedly just a join table.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Yes, looks like it. It can probably be dropped unless there is some other information stored there, like maybe role assignment timestamp or something.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class that'll hold everything you need and pass an instance of that class to your view as the model.

Answer (score 2):

Create a view-specific model that holds your File, User, and Role.  Select a new one of these in your query.  Set this as the model for your ViewPage.

Model

```
public class OwnedFile
{
    File File { get; set; }
    User User { get; set; }
    Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Query

```
var files = from f in filesContext.Files
                join u in filesContext.aspnet_Users on f.Uploader equals u.UserId
                join uir in filesContext.aspnet_UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals uir.UserId
                join ur in filesContext.aspnet_Roles on uir.RoleId equals ur.RoleId
                select new OwnedFile { File = f, User = u, Role = ur };
```

View

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Bailiffs.Models.OwnedFile>>"
```